# Dagger 2: Unable to inject singleton in other scope

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have Singleton scoped module that provides some standard singletons: Application, DB services, etc.
But for Activity I have separate module that should create Presenter for he Activity and I need to pass Application context to it. However I get following error when trying to compile the project:

```
Error:(13, 1) error: xxx.SplashComponent scoped with @xxx.ViewScope may not reference bindings with different scopes:
@Provides @Singleton xxx.ApplicationModule.provideAppContext()
```

Here is snippet of my Application module:

```
@Singleton
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

    private Application app;

    public ApplicationModule(Application app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("ui")
    Scheduler provideUIScheduler() {
        return AndroidSchedulers.mainThread();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("io")
    Scheduler provideIOScheduler() {
        return Schedulers.io();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Application provideApplication() {
        return app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Context provideAppContext() {
        return app;
    }
}
```

And here is Activity module and Component:

```
@Module
public class SplashModule {
    private final FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    public SplashModule(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {

        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    }

    @Provides
    @ViewScope
    Presenter getPresenter(Context context) {
        return new SplashPresenter(context, fragmentManager);
    }
}
```

Component:

```
@ViewScope
@Component(modules = {SplashModule.class, ApplicationModule.class})
public interface SplashComponent {
    void inject(SplashActivity activity);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks. After I looked at your error message, I understood that my Module file contained methods with different scopes. For instance, "@ FirstScope @ Binds Class1 method1()" and "@ SecondScope @ Binds Class2 method2()".

Answer (score 17):

> What am I doing wrong?

This:

```
@ViewScope
@Component(modules = {SplashModule.class /*View scoped*/,
    ApplicationModule.class/*Singleton scoped*/})
```

You can only include unscoped or modules scoped with the *same* scope in your components. You will need to use more than one component.

To include the dependencies from your application, you need to have them in a different component, e.g. `ApplicationComponent`. If yo do this, you have 2 options: either declare `SplashComponent` as a `SubComponent` of `ApplicationComponent` or add `ApplicationComponent` as a dependency to your component. If you add it as a dependency, be sure to also provide methods in your `ApplicationComponent`, so that it can access the dependencies.

e.g. if you were to use component dependencies:

```
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    void inject(MyApplication app);

    // todo: also add getters for your other dependencies you need further down the graph
    Application getApplication();

}

@Component(modules = {SplashModule.class}, dependencies={ApplicationComponent.class})
public interface SplashComponent {
    // as before
}
```

Comment: Still can`t understand

Answer (score 12):

I want to explain some key points of Dagger 2 from my understanding.

**Main actors:**

- "Component"  is the bridge between modules and places where injection happens.
- "Module"     is the place where we declare our objects which will be injected.
- "Scope"      is like the life-time of related injection story.

**How does it work?**

- Declare component with a scope ("Singleton").
- Define modules that can inject the required objects in the component's   modules list.

void inject(BaseFragment baseFragment);

*******Expose the provided objects in the component's module to sub components****
 DbHelper dbHelper();

- Declare module and provides objects to be injected via component.

Ex:

```
@Singleton 
@Component(modules = { ApplicationModule.class, NetworkModule.class })
public interface ApplicationComponent {

  void inject(BaseActivity baseActivity);
  DbHelper dbHelper();
}




@PerService @Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class, modules = ServiceModule.class)
public interface ServiceComponent {

  void inject(SyncService service);

}
```

// SyncService.java

```
  @Inject DbHelper dbHelper;  (even Singleton scoped)

  private void setupInjector() {
    ServiceComponent mServiceComponent = DaggerServiceComponent.builder()
        .applicationComponent(getApplicationComponent())
        .serviceModule(new ServiceModule(this))
        .build();
    mServiceComponent.inject(this);
  }
```

ok then...[image]

You can inject both unscoped and (Singleton and PerService) scoped objects to your SyncService.class

Comment: Exposing stuff like `DbHelper dbHelper()` was what I was missing all the time. Thanks so much for this answer.

Comment: I have to correct you a bit about "Singleton is the default". No-scope is the default not Singleton. Without @Singleton you'll have a new instance on every injection.

Comment: @WindRider you're right. Thats why we marked some components as Singleton for avoiding to create expensive objects each time.

Comment: Actually, it's created every time it's injected so its effective scope is actually the consumer's scope.

Comment: what do you mean by consumer's scope?

Comment: WindRider means if your object is allowed to have multiple instances throughout your application lifecycle, then you'll get a new object every time you inject. For instance, even if you don't annotate the Application instance with `@Singleton` every time you inject `Application`, it will return the same instance. Now, let's say you have `GrumpyFragment`, you'll get a new instance every time you inject a `GrumpyFragment`. Because the Android system restricts the `Application` object to have only one instance but for `Fragment` there is no such restriction.

Comment: Here, `Application` and `Fragment` are consumers and their scope, by default, are `@Singleton` and `No Scope` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

> **Scoping rules:**
>
> - When a type is marked with a scope annotation, it can only be used by Components that are annotated with the same scope.
> - When a Component is marked with a scope annotation, it can only provide types with that annotation or types that have no annotation.
> - A subcomponent cannot use a scope annotation used by one of its parent Components.
>
> Components also involve subcomponents in this context.
>
> **Caution:- Modules that use a scope annotation can only be used in components that are annotated with the same scope.** [Check Here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-android#dagger-scopes).

For more information on Dagger in Android go through [this training](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection) and practise [it here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-dagger/#1).